# Are Flutter Windows App faster than Native Windows App?

Tags: windows, flutter

Are Flutter Windows App faster than Native Windows App ?

I am using Flutter to develop Android apps and wanted to know if Flutter is good for developing Windows app.
Also if flutter unix apps are faster than native apps developed in Unix ?

Comment: Faster?  Not likely.  Flutter is a layer on top of the Windows and linux native UI APIs.  Your flutter code is converted into win32 API calls on Windows.

Comment: Flutter is also not faster than native android or iOS, so faster should not be the only requirement when considering desktop development in flutter. Windows would be UWP or WPF development in C# & XAML, which is generally an unenjoyable experience (in my opinion).